# How to run a system command in browser using PHP and Xampp?

Tags: php, database

I am having the command line to backup the db and wnat to run through the browser.How can I do it.Because when I execute the below code with the inputs it wont give me the output.Why?How can I achieve the db backup if it is not work out.

```
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile"; 
print system($command);
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is passthru()

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/passthru), it will dump the output of the command directly back to the browser.

```
$ret_val = null;
header("Content-type: application/gzip");
passthru("mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip", $ret_code);
# the extra equals sign below makes sure $ret_val isn't null
if($ret_val !== 0) 
   echo "Failboat";
```

That being said, this sounds like a really brittle way to do backups. You'd be better off saving the file to disk first and downloading seperately. IF you really want to get hacky with it though, try using tee to write the file to disk while streaming it back to the browser (warning, that's actually an even worse idea)

Comment: I hope his backup page is really well secured, I wouldn't like some random people to get access to my database dumps directly...

Comment: @RageZ: agreed. This is probably one of those times where what was asked for isn't really what's wanted

Comment: It also return the empty zip.I didnt get the result

Answer (score 1):

I would say one of this functions [system](http://fr.php.net/system) or [exec](http://fr.php.net/exec). If you need the ouput exec would be better

```
system($command)
```

Just for your reference the function signature from the doc

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

and a quick snippet

```
exec($command, $output, $ret_var);
echo "return code: {$ret_var}" . PHP_EOL;
echo "output ------" . PHP_EOL;
foreach($output as $line){
    print $line . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I tried that But I cant get the result.I updated my coding.It wont print anything

Comment: @vinothkumar: what do you mean by cannot get the result?

Comment: The expected output is the zip file of database.That I didnt get.Thats why i put I cant(I didnt get the expected result).

Comment: @vinothkumar: did you check the return value if it is not 0. I suspect your webserver doesn't have permissions to write the zip file.

Comment: But when I export through phpmyadmin it gives the zip file.

Comment: probably because phpmyadmin is using a proper directory to do it like `/tmp` ... anyway check the return code it would tell if it has worked or not ...

Comment: I am not  sure whether you are asking the result of print in system command.Anyway it doesnt print anything on the browser.I tried echo and exe aslo.

Comment: it won't print anything the output of the comment is stored in the second argument variable of the call the return value in third

Comment: echo $ret_var."<br/>";
print_r($output); It gives like the 255 in next line
Array ( )

Comment: ok 255 is not 0 so there is something wrong with your command check if you have permissions, or even try the command for a shell just to see if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Eigther use [mysqladmin](http://www.mysql-admin.org/) ([english version)](http://www.mysql-admin.org/index.php?bereich=all_files) or you may use an ajax call (over javascript) in one of your own pages.

Comment: Is there any way to make it simple.Not want to install and use all the files from mysqladmin

Comment: No, there is no partial version. Myasqladmin is a free GUI for all possible DB-issues.